JsonConverters in Durable Functions Isolated model
I am moving a Durable Functions app from the in-process model to the isolated model.
I have some messages sent between orchestrators and activities and between activities which require custom serialization.
Currently I register my JsonConverter's using IMessageSerializerSettingsFactory in Startup.cs as per "Customizing serialization with Dependency Injection".
IMessageSerializerSettingsFactory does not appear available in the isolated model.
Microsoft docs makes reference to WorkerOptions.Serializer but doesn't provide an example.
How can I register my JsonConverter's so that they are used during message serialization in the isolated model?
Update
Here's what I've come up with so far but it would be good to have some comments/confirmation on the approach.
Startup.cs
builder.Services.AddOptions<JsonSerializerOptions>()
    .Configure(options =>
    {
        options.Converters.Add(MyConverter);
        options.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
    });

builder.Services.AddOptions<WorkerOptions>()
    .Configure(options =>
    {
        options.Serializer = new JsonObjectSerializer(
            builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider()
                .GetRequiredService<JsonSerializerOptions>());
    });

I am hoping that the second registration is adopted by the Functions runtume for all serialization that it carries out (messages between Activities) and the first registration lets me inject options where I can specifically do the serialization myself for example when returning an HttpResponseData from an Http trigger:
    req.CreateResponse().WriteAsJsonAsync(poco,
        new JsonObjectSerializer(
            new JsonSerializerOptions(...)));


After much browsing around I found this Azure Functions Isolated configuration sample.
